# Error setting up php and apache - .dll file could not be found

Tags: php, apache, dll

I'm setting up php and apache on my computer. I have modified my httpd.conf file like my book says (so add these lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/WebSite/PHP//php5apache2.dll
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml .php
```

)

But when I try to start apache, I get this error: Syntax error on line 129 of httpd.conf Cannot load C:/WebSite/PHP/php5apache2.dll onto server. The specified module could not be found.

The file is definitely in the specified directory. I am new to this, have I done something wrong? Help appreciated :)

EDIT: I actually got the "tumbleweed" badge for this question. Is anyone going to bother looking at it?

Comment: I would try to change it like this: `LoadModule php5_module "C:/WebSite/PHP/php5apache2.dll"`Also, you need to ensure that apache user has an access to that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just had the same error on windows 7 with PHP 5.5 (5.5.0) VC11 and Apache 2.2.22.
The offending line was

LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

and the error was "... line 129 ... The specified module could not be found."
(Yes - I checked that this file existed and all users had access to it!)

I downgraded the PHP to PHP 5.4 (5.4.16) VC9 - making only one change [see below - they seem to have changed the name of the file - between versions] - and it worked fine!

LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll"

This is a pretty simple fix.

I'm not sure why this works, but 
I did notice on http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5 that there was some mention of ...
"The VC11 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 x86 or x64 installed."
I only have Visual Studio 2008 installed - and this seems to be compatible with VC9 (according to the same site) - which may account for both the problem and the fix?

Comment: Very good answer. However, I actually eventually just installed XAMPP and it was all configured fine ;)